# Proper method for Request 2.0 user-generated request after form submission

Tags: facebook, forms, request, facebook-javascript-sdk

Scratching my head on this one:

I'm working on an iframe-canvas app. After the user makes their selections in a form and chooses friends with a custom jquery form selector, they submit the form to a page on my site that handles the form info.

I need to use Facebook's sendRequestToManyRecipients JavaScript function to complete the user-generated request flow and send a notification. If I place the sendRequestToManyRecipients function on my page I get the FB pop-up and the notification gets sent just fine.

The only problem with that workflow is that it visually takes the user out of Facebook and the Facebook UI.

What's the recommended method to handle this? When the person submits the form and it goes to my site briefly to handle the form, do I then redirect with the recipients' Facebook user ids in URL variables?

For example:

apps.facebook.com/myapp?recipients=1234,5678,9101112

and then call the sendRequestToManyRecipients function with that variable? Is there a better way to do this? Is it best to hide those variables somehow from the URL in the user's address bar?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I was able to pass the get variables back to the Facebook app. Only issue I'm seeing now is the "secure content" issue in Facebook. See my comment at http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5212016/facebook-javascript-sdk-over-https-loading-non-secure-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, passing GET varibales seemed to have worked.

In Firefox that is, but sadly not in IE9. See [IE9 Error SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised after redirect (plus only secure content message)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7866581/ie9-error-sec7111-https-security-is-compromised-after-redirect-plus-only-secu)